class keyword for UPROPERTY()
I'm new to UnrealEngine and studying C++ development in scope of games. For now I read a tutorial where I should create a AMyPawn and UPawnMovementComponent to attach it then.
Here is the definition for class derived from APawn and I want to add some properties for it as we commonly do in UE

UCLASS()
class V4_FYRSTI_API AMyPawn : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this pawn's properties
    AMyPawn();

    UPROPERTY(EditAnyWhere)
    class UCustomMovementComponent* Movement; // class KeyWord + Type + varName

    UPROPERTY()
    class UParticleSystemComponent* ParticleComp; // class KeyWord + Type + varName

    UPROPERTY()
    UStaticMeshComponent* VisualMesh; // Just Type + varName

    virtual UPawnMovementComponent* GetMovementComponent() const override;
protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;



I found it interesting that I should declare StaticMesh instance by a type-word and variable name, but another fields for particles or movement component I have to add "class" keyword at the beginning, why?
I thought it may be related to "Class Reference Variable" as we have "Object Reference Var", but when I try to add "class" keyword to another field, it bring no changes or crashes the project at all.

class is part of the type. So for example class UParticleSystemComponent* ParticleComp; say that the variable ParticleComp is a pointer to a UParticleSystemComponent class. If you try to use it for something that is not a class then you will get an error.

While creating games is a fun way to learn programming, the course you're taking might go a little too fast, or you have missed or misunderstood a lecture. But if you're really serious about learning C++, then I recommend you learn the language first, preferably though a good book or two. Then it's much easier to follow along in the course you're taking. But, to really learn making games there's a lot of other things you need to learn, especially math, design, and more.

I updated the code to bring more actual details of my issue. I'm not new at classes and OOP in C++, I have a problem with a class field declaration. Have you seen it before we need to write "class" before the type of the class field, send me example links if you got, thanks

UE includes a lot of black magic (either via macros or via their own in-house tools) in code which at points seems like empty code (for example empty macros), but in reality it does generate some metadata at some point. There may also be some UE-specific best-practices which are not exactly real use-cases for "normal" C++. I recommend you start with vanilla C++ projects, not game engines, if you're new to this. It's like starting C# via Unity and then switching to .NET in Azure and wondering why everything is different. For one thing, over-extensive use of macros is discouraged in C++.

Prefixing the class type with class allows one to use a class name which has not been declared. In order to declare the Movement variable above, the code would have to do one of three things:

Include the CustomMovementComponent.h header from this class header. This increases the amount of potentially unnecessary recompilation that would be necessary following changes to a class definition.
Declare class UCustomMovementComponent in the global scope above the class definition (a "forward declaration"). This is fine, but it puts the declaration far from the use, and encourages long and uncontextualized lists of classes at the top of the header file.
Use the name class UCustomMovementComponent when defining Movement. This serves as a combined forward declaration and variable definition.

Unreal code tends to go with #3. Of course, if the class is such a common one that it tends to be included everywhere (as would be the case for UStaticMeshComponent) the forward declaration is not strictly necessary, so for these fundamental engine classes one tends to see fewer forward decls.
Note that this all applies to the use of incomplete (forward-declared but not yet defined) classes. You could not write a function involving UCustomMovementComponent's properties, or even a class which had a UCustomMovementComponent rather than a UCustomMovementComponent*, without including the actual header. So you'll see those #includes in the corresponding .cpp. Keeping them out of the header reduces transient dependencies, which is important to Unreal because they try to keep modules as independent as possible.

In 99.999% of all cases the class keyword is not needed. But C++ have inherited a "feature" from C where class and structure tag names are placed in kind of their own namespace (which is different from the C++ namespace).
That means you can have a class named Foo but also a variable named Foo. Then you need to distinguish between the class and the variable, which is done by adding the class keyword to the declaration.
Because of this, it's possible to declare a variable like
Foo Foo;  // Declare a variable named Foo, with the type class Foo

After this, all mentions of Foo in the current (or nested) scope refers to the variable not the class. To use the class again, for example when declaring new variables, you need to use the class keyword to explicitly tell the compiler that you want to use the class, not the variable:
class Foo Bar;  // Declare a variable named Bar, with the type class Foo


True, but in the case of UE, it's mostly for use of forward declarations.
